# How to understand the posterior distribution is the same as likelihood function

Tags: bayesian, density-function, likelihood

So I read this post [Why is the posterior distribution the same as the likelihood function when uniform prior distribution is used in Bayesian Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/483338), and learned that when we have a uniform prior, the posterior distribution is the same as the likelihood function. However, we also have that [What is the reason that a likelihood function is not a pdf](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31238/what-is-the-reason-that-a-likelihood-function-is-not-a-pdf), i.e. likelihood is not a pdf. For example, the sum of the likelihood might not be 1.

Given these, how should we understand the posterior distribution is the same as the likelihood function when we have a uniform prior? Does this mean the sum of a posterior distribution doesn't need to be 1?

Comment: It might help to realize that in many cases uniform priors just can't exist.  The standard example is any location family of distributions.

Comment: The likelihood function may need to be normalized in order to integrate to one, so it may be that they are the same up to a constant of proportionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a Bayesian posterior is derived from a likelihood function that does not integrate (or sum) to unity the posterior function is simply re-scaled to make that integral (or sum) equal one in order that the posterior can be a 'proper' probability distribution.

The use of a uniform prior makes the scaled likelihood function into the posterior and so it might make one wonder whether such a Bayesian approach offers anything beyond a pure likelihood approach. See these little books if you are interested in likelihood-based inference: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/735705.Likelihood
https://www.routledge.com/Statistical-Evidence-A-Likelihood-Paradigm/Royall/p/book/9780412044113

Answer (score 1):

*The likelihood function is defined up to a multiplicative constant.* For instance, the likelihood associated with an ordered sample of size n is n! times the likelihood associated with the unordered sample. More generaly, the likelihood associated with a sufficient statistic is proportional to the likelihood associated with the original sample.

Furthermore, *the likelihood function is parameterisation invariant* in that changing the parameterisation of the model does not change the likelihood function, in the sense that $\ell_\eta(\eta_0)=\ell_theta(\theta_0)$ if $\eta=F(\theta)$ and $\eta_0=F(\theta_0)$. This means that the likelihood function does not obey the change-of-variable rule for density functions, i.e., no Jacobian appears in the transform. Therefore, this is a further argument for [likelihoods not being pdfs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31238/what-is-the-reason-that-a-likelihood-function-is-not-a-pdf).

**A formal equality between a likelihood and a posterior density thus does not signify much, as it depends on arbitrary choices of parameterisation and statistics.**